# Could not load file or assembly 'PCLAppConfig' in UWP project

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I have a Xamarin project with iOS, Android and UWP projects.

I have installed the version 1.0.1 from nuGet in all three projects and in .net standard's one.

The iOS and Android projects works fine but when I run the UWP project this error is triggered:

`System.IO.FileLoadException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'PCLAppConfig, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)'`

The compile works fine, only at runtime the error come.

How can I solve this error?

**EDIT**

Maybe I found the problem but I cannot resolve it.

From nuGet I have installed the latest version, the 1.01 but the version of the DLL is the 0.4.0.

Maybe UWP read the 0.4.0 version and triggers the error?

Comment: Which version of UWP are you targeting?

Comment: This one https://imgur.com/JWksX9q.

Comment: convert the [PCL to .net standard project](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tafuji.pcl2netstandard)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. The PCL is a .net standard project.

Comment: this is a bug in the nuget package with the version mismatch. When I compile the code on my own the UWP version also has same version.